# Debian change server and SSL problem TLS 1.2 to TLS 1.0

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, php-5.3, tls1.0, debian-7.6.0

I want to switch server Gentoo -> Debian 7 (with php 5.3, Yes i know, but i've an old code)

When I copy SSL's certificats to the new server, I've a problem, it downgrade to TLS 1.2 to TLS 1.0.

I don't understood.. I've install Open SSL 1.1.1c, I've restart apache and I've always this problem.

Here is my vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName myserver.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
<Directory /var/www/html/site/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/server-ca.crt
SSLProtocol All -SSLv3 -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite 'EDH+CAMELLIA:EDH+aRSA:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:+CAMELLIA256:+AES256:+CAMELLIA128:+AES128:+SSLv3:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!DSS:!RC4:!SEED:!ECDSA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:AE$
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
</VirtualHost>
```

What I can do to resolv this ?
Thank a lot